# A float is stuck warning in Revtex4-2

Tags: floats, equations

How to remove this warning in a revtex4-2 file.

A float is stuck (cannot be placed) on line 203.
Where line 203 is having an equation.

Tried placing equation in `\begin{figure}`, `\end{figure}` body.
It generated the same warning for `\section{}` line.

Comment: I got rid of that warning by manually changing the placement of the figure.

Comment: It is hard to tell what caused this error, since you did not provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Since you seem to have found a solution on your own, I am voting to close this question.